# Github wrong username

Tags: github, account

I have setup with guthub with a previous github account on this computer called myaccount when i run this command

```
ssh -T git@github.com
Hi myaccount! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Ok but i have now setup a new github account called samaccount but i cant run this command i get this error.

```
git push -u origin master
```

i get this error

```
ERROR: Permission to samueleast/Samuel-East-S3-Audio-Playlist-Player.git denied to myaccount.
```

I dont want it to use myaccount it should be using samaccount !!!

i have followed all the steps here http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/
setup brand new ssh key.

and also run this command many times

```
git config --global user.name "samaccount"
```

but it still uses myaccount its sooo annoying where am i going wrong???

Comment: so you setup two github account on the same computer? did you upload the same keys? i mean the `id_rsa.pub`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

GitHub recognizes you as `myaccount` because SSH is using a key that corresponds to a public key that has been added to the `myaccount` account on the GitHub website.

If you want to switch entirely to using the `sameueleast` account instead of `myaccount`, you can do the following:

- Login to GitHub's website as `myaccount`
- Go to "Account Settings"
- Go to "SSH Public Keys"
- Delete your public key from that list
- Logout
- Login to GitHub's website as `samueleast`
- Go to "Account Settings" -> "SSH Public Keys"
- Select "Add another public key" and paste in the contents of your public key.  You public key will (probably) be called `id_rsa.pub` or `id_dsa.pub` and be in your `.ssh` directory.

On the other hand, if you want to be able to use either `myaccount` or `samueleast` when pushing to GitHub, you will need to create aliases for `git@github.com` in `~/.ssh/config`, such as:

```
Host github-myaccount
    User git
    Hostname github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa-myaccount.pub

Host github-samueleast
    User git
    Hostname github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa-samueleast.pub
```

That assumes you've generated a second SSH keypair and given them names as above.  Then you need to make sure that you are using the appropriate alias in the URLs of your git remotes.  For example, if you want to change your `origin` remote so that pushing to origin means "pushing to origin as samueleast", you could do:

```
 git remote set-url origin \
     git@github-samueleast:samueleast/Samuel-East-S3-Audio-Playlist-Player.git
```

Comment: IdentityFile should be the path to the *private* not public key, no?