# Github - I switched accounts and now I can't push because I have the wrong username

Tags: git, github, account

So I'm now "jononomo" on github.  A year ago, however, I was "zononomo".  I quit software for a while and bought a new laptop in the interim.  Then I came back and created a new account on Github under the handle "jononomo" and now I'm trying to sync my dotfiles between my two laptops.  From my new laptop I created a git repository and pushed it up to github where it can be viewed under the "jononomo" account.  Then I went to my old laptop and cloned this repository.  Everything worked as expected.

Then I made some changes to my dotfiles on my old laptop and now I'd like to push these changes to github so that I can then pull them down to my new laptop.  The problem is that when I run the command:

```
git push origin master
```

I get the error message:

```
ERROR: Permission to jononomo/.dotfiles.git denied to zononomo.
```

The first thing I did was blow away my old SSH keys in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.  Then I generated new SSH keys and added my new public key to my jononomo github account.  But that didn't fix the problem.  If I run the command:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I get the response:

```
Hi zononomo! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Next, I followed the solution given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8152291/1701170  This person suggested that I create a `~/.ssh/config` file with the following contents:

```
Host github-jononomo
    User git
    Hostname github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
```

and then he suggested I run the command:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github-jononomo:jononomo/.dotfiles.git
```

I tried that, but it didn't fix my issue.  I'm still getting the message:

```
ERROR: Permission to jononomo/.dotfiles.git denied to zononomo.
```

Incidentally, my `.gitconfig` has the following contents:

```
[user]
    name = Jon Crowell
    email = me@myemail.com
[github]
    user = jononomo
    token = 2a18a7235746324aefec34b234aa343a
    email = me@myemail.com
[credential]
    helper = osxkeychain
```

Comment: Please don't edit your answers into the question. You need to post them *as answers*, so they can be accepted. It is completely acceptable to post and accept an answer to your own question.

Comment: Ack, you deleted my answer but didn't re-post it anywhere!  Maybe I can find a cached version of the page...

Comment: okay, I've re-posted the answer below after retrieving it from the old revision.  I guess now someone can vote and give me reputation, so thanks for the tip, meagar.

Comment: Click the "X minutes ago" above my name to review the entire edit history of your question. You can do this for any post on the site...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

zononomo? GitHub shouldn't recognize you as zononomo anymore.
Maybe you have an ssh agent delivering your old key?

As suggested in "[Having Trouble Switching Github accounts on terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548158/having-trouble-switching-github-accounts-on-terminal)", add the line:

```
 IdentitiesOnly yes
```

to your config file and see if GitHub is still using that old id.

> however I'm still getting the

```
 ssh: Could not resolve hostname github: nodename nor servname provided, or not known error
```

The "`hostname`" to resolve must match the `Host` entry of the config file.

If that `Host` entry is github-jononomo, you must use it in your ssh address as well:

```
git remote set-url origin github-jononomo:jononomo/.dotfiles.git
```

Comment: I logged into my old github account, removed the SSH stuff, then completely deleted the account.  Now I'm getting a different error: "ssh: Could not resolve hostname github: nodename nor servname provided, or not known"  I'll try your suggestion right now...

Comment: Okay, I added a config file to my `~/.ssh/` directory.  It contains the following text: `Host github.com
    User           git
    IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes`  -- however I'm still getting the `"ssh: Could not resolve hostname github: nodename nor servname provided, or not known` error.  I guess I'll start googling that error now.

Comment: @JonCrowell you need to use the entry you put on Host: github-jononomo. So use `git remote set-url origin github-jononomo:jononomo/.dotfiles.git`, and make sure to use `github-jononomo` as `Host`, while keeping hostname to `github.com`

Comment: @JonCrowell you probably did it, but check your email also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597096/git-github-remembers-wrong-account/12597211#12597211

Comment: @JonCrowell see as examples of config file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551448/change-github-account-mac-command-line/9551540#9551540, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066895/how-to-work-on-personal-github-repo-from-office-computer-whose-ssh-key-is-alread/12066973#12066973 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041082/how-to-add-deploy-key-for-2-repo-with-1-user-on-github/10042145#10042145

Comment: @JonCrowell or use an https address ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377703/syncing-with-github/5378094#5378094

Comment: Okay, I got it to work.  I will post a note to the bottom of my question that will give the steps I took.  I had to get the `~/.ssh/config` file correct, I guess.

Comment: The `git remote set-url origin` is a must-do after setting hostname in `~/.ssh/config`

Answer (score 4):

I got it to work by taking the following steps:

First my `~/.ssh/config` file is as follows:

```
Host github-jononomo
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile  ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Second, I ran the command `git remote set-url origin git@github-jononomo:jononomo/.dotfiles.git`

Third, I ran the command `ssh -T git@github.com` and got the result `Hi jononomo! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

Fourth, I logged in to my old github account, removed the SSH key and completely deleted the account.

Many thanks to VonC.

Comment: Good feedback. +1. Note: you don't need the `git@` in your remote url (because of the `User` entry in your config file)

Comment: Thanks for the tip -- I was actually wondering about that.